# XML - XSL - Select only first element that matches condition

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xpath-1.0

Let asssume, that I do have array of **MyObject** elements, that has some property, let say **IsFinalResult**, based on which I would like to conditionally select item.
I want that logic will take only **first** element from array, that matches given condition **IsFinalResult == true** (even if multiply elements matches condition).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="ArrayOfMyObject/MyObject">
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="// Here how to check?">
               // this will match only once
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I can do this only withn XPath 1.0.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do when your condition is matched, and what do you want to do otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the `position()` function

```
<xsl:when test="position() = 1 and IsFinalResult='true'">
   // this will match only once
</xsl:when>
```

---

But there are also other ways to handle this situation.
One of them is to use template matching with predicates:

```
<xsl:template match="/ArrayOfMyObject/MyObject[IsFinalResult = 'true' and position() = 1]">
  <!-- For the first MyObject element -->
  ...
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="/ArrayOfMyObject/MyObject[IsFinalResult = 'true' and position() > 1]">
  <!-- For all the other MyObject elements -->
  ...
```

---

Inspired by the comment below, there is another way to read your question (which I had in one of the previous versions of this answer). This way can be realized by using two separate conditions:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ArrayOfMyObject/MyObject[IsFinalResult='true']">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
      // this will match only once
    </xsl:when>
  ...
```

The second way changes as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="/ArrayOfMyObject/MyObject[IsFinalResult = 'true'][1]">
  <!-- Matches the first element of the list of elements that satisfy the first predicate -->
  ...
```

Here the `[1]` is not necessary - consider it a way to emphasize the readability.
And

```
<xsl:template match="/ArrayOfMyObject/MyObject[IsFinalResult = 'true'][position() > 1]">
  <!-- Matches all the other elements of the list of elements that satisfy the first predicate -->
  ...
```

Comment: There is a difference between *the first element that matches the condition* (which I think is what this question is about) and *the first element, if it matches the condition* (which I think is what your answer does).

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a template approach...

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="ArrayOfMyObject/MyObject" />
</xsl:template>
```

Then, to represent your `xsl:when` test, to match the first of the "IsFinalResult='true'" elements, the template match would be this...

```
<xsl:template match="MyObject[@IsFinalResult='true'][1]">
```

(Note, I am assuming `IsFinalResult` is an attribute here. If not, just remove the `@` prefix)

And to represent your `xsl:otherwise`, have a template (with a lower priority) that will pick up all the other `MyObject` elements

```
<xsl:template match="MyObject">
```

So, given the following XML:

```
<ArrayOfMyObject>
    <MyObject IsFinalResult="false">1</MyObject>
    <MyObject IsFinalResult="false">2</MyObject>
    <MyObject IsFinalResult="true">3</MyObject>
    <MyObject IsFinalResult="false">4</MyObject>
    <MyObject IsFinalResult="true">5</MyObject>
    <MyObject IsFinalResult="true">6</MyObject>
</ArrayOfMyObject>
```

If you apply this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ArrayOfMyObject/MyObject" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="MyObject[@IsFinalResult='true'][1]">
    <When>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </When>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="MyObject">
    <Otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </Otherwise>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is this...

```
<Otherwise>1</Otherwise>
<Otherwise>2</Otherwise>
<When>3</When>
<Otherwise>4</Otherwise>
<Otherwise>5</Otherwise>
<Otherwise>6</Otherwise>
```

(Change the template match to `<xsl:template match="MyObject[@IsFinalResult='true' and position() = 1]">` if you only want to consider `@IsFinalResult='true'` if it is the very first child element).

Note that, if you only wanted your `xsl:otherwise` to handle elements where `IsFinalResult="true"` (after the first one), you just need to add a third template, to ignore the other elements

```
<xsl:template match="MyObject[not(@IsFinalResult='true')]" />
```